# trying to send https string to website in lua

Tags: lua

I am sort of new to lua and I have API that I need to call.

`"https://status.abc.com/integrations/plus/?endpoint="..number.."&server="..server`

This is not in a json format.  It is just sending this http string to a web server.  What is the simplest way to acomplish this?

Comment: Provided you have to to send a TLS request, I'll recommend you to use [Lua cURL](https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv3) for the request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try looking into the [LuaSec](https://github.com/brunoos/luasec) library.
There is no https support native to lua so your (as far as i know) only option is to build LuaSec or try to find a build on the internet

Answer (score 0):

local ok =os.execute([[curl --cert /etc/openvpn/cert.crt --key /etc/openvpn/key.key  -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 'url here' --data 'data here']])